# Question about Flask Template rendering/generating

Tags: python, flask

I need to render the number of buttons specified in the configuration file.
This number of buttons does not change while the application is running.

For example I have Flask application:

```
# config.py
BUTTONS = (
    ("btn1", "val1"), 
    ("btn2", "val2"),
    ("btn3", "val3"),
)
```

```
# __init__.py
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile("config.py")

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template("example.html")
```

```
# example.html
{% for btn in config["BUTTONS"] %}
<button name={{ btn[0] }} value= {{ btn[1] }}> {{ btn[0] }} </button>
{% endfor %}
```

0. Is it a good idea to do so? If No: How I can achieve such result?
1. Does flask would re-render this template on every request? Or Flask understands that there is a constant variable and there is no need re-render this? Does Flask have something like template caching system?
2. Is it good idea to write *template html generator* for such *constant* variables?
   Just script running before app is started. This script will generate render this template to file (e.g "rendered_example.html") and then:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return *read_file*("rendered_example.html")
```

3. Or I don't need to care about it because either solution doesn't really affect performance?
4. Or I need to save buttons count in Database (outside of config file)?